# How to make potions in mobile edition

Tags: terraria-mobile

How do you make potions in Terraria mobile edition?

Answer (score 0):

> Most potions can be crafted at a Placed Bottle or Alchemy Table, but flasks must be crafted at an Imbuing Station. [Says the wiki.](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Potion)

[An extensive guide on crafting can be found here.](http://www.gamedynamo.com/article/cheats/5387/3489/en/pc/terraria)